# Angular 2 - Emitting a value from a component that needs to be used in another component's input

Tags: angular

I have a component that emits an object to its parent component that needs to be used as the input for a different component in that parent component. As confusing as that sentence was, here is my code:

In my parent component called `project.component.ts`, here are my relevant functions:

```
/**
   *  Set the account to edit
   */
  public accountToEdit: any = {};
  setAccountToEdit(account) {
    this.accountToEdit = account;
  }
```

In the `project.component.html`:

```
<app-project-accounts
      [projectId]="projectId"
      (accountToEdit)="setAccountToEdit($event)"
      (openCreateAccountModal)="openCreateAccount()"></app-project-accounts>


<!-- New Project Account modal -->
<project-account-create-edit
  [projectId]="projectId"
  [accountToEdit]="accountToEdit"
  (toggleVisibility)="toggleProjectAccountModalVisibility($event)"
  [visible]="projectAccountVisible">
></project-account-create-edit>
```

Now for the `project-accounts.component.ts` file, I have a button that when clicked, triggers this function:

```
/**
   *  Open the modal for updating an account
   */
  openEdit(account) {
    this.openCreateAccountModal.emit(true);
    this.accountToEdit.emit(account);
  }
```

The Problem: It would seem that when my modal (`project-account-create-edit`) opens, it doesn't get the `this.accountToEdit` input passed to it until after the modal closes.

Could this be that each time the input changes, it's only updating the modal when it's in a closed state?

All I need to do is get the `this.accountToEdit` variable from `project.component.ts` inside of the input for the component `project-account-create-edit`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does ``openCreateAccount()`` do?

Comment: It basically sets a variable to true so that the modal opens: openCreateAccount() {
    this.projectAccountVisible = true;
  }

Comment: Does setting the ``visible`` property to true on ``project-account-create-edit`` trigger the ``toggleVisibility`` output? What does the ``toggleProjectAccountModalVisibility($event)`` do?

Comment: Yes, the visible property triggers the `toggleVisibility` and `toggleProjectAccountModalVisibility($event)` actually emits another event to set the `visible` input. It seems when `visible` is set to false, the value of the `accountToEdit` populates, but when it's true, it's empty :/

Comment: Possibly you have an infinite input->output->input->output event loop? I would try disabling the ``toggleVisibility`` output, see if this helps?

Comment: Ehh nothing :/ You know, do you know of any documentation that might help? I feel it would be common for a parent component to contain the state of a variable that gets updated and can be passed to other child components.

Comment: Ahh so I needed to use ngOnChanges() to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

So after much toying around, I needed to use `ngOnChanges()` to get the component to see the changes. I added this code:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {

    if(changes.accountToEdit) {
      this.accountToEditChanged = changes.accountToEdit.currentValue;

      console.log('this.account', this.accountToEditChanged);
      if(this.accountToEditChanged.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
        this.isEditing = true;
        this.createAccountForm.controls['name'].setValue(this.accountToEditChanged.name);
        this.createAccountForm.controls['coding'].setValue(this.accountToEditChanged.coding);
      } else {
        this.accountToEditChanged = {};
        this.isEditing = false;
      }

    }
 }
```

Cheers!